# Solving the wave equation for one-electron atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, hydrogen

While solving the wave equation for a hydrogen atom, the first part of the solution is solving for the $\Phi(\phi)$.

We have
$$\frac{1}{\Phi}\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial\phi^2}=-m^2$$

which has the solution,

$$\Phi(\phi)=e^{jm\phi}$$

where $m$ in integers.

Why are only integral values of $m$ allowed as a solution for $\Phi$?

The textbook says "Since the wave function must be single-valued, we impose the condition that $m$ is an integer..", but I have trouble understanding this part.

Comment: In the single electron atom, you are looking for resonant conditions for a 3D standing wave. Resonant conditions in a standing wave are generally associated with integer solutions.

Comment: Why was the question down voted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $\phi$ is the polar angle, i.e. it changes from $0$ to $2\pi$. Any change greater than that takes us a full rotation around the center of the coordinates, to the point where we have already been, i.e. we should get the same value of the wave function. Mathematically this may be expressed as:
\begin{equation}
\Phi(\phi + 2\pi) = \Phi(\phi).
\end{equation}

If we now take the solution in the form $\Phi(\phi) = e^{i\lambda\phi}$, then
\begin{equation}
\Phi(\phi + 2\pi) = e^{i\lambda(\phi+2\pi)} = e^{i\lambda\phi} = \Phi(\phi),
\end{equation}
which implies that
\begin{equation}
e^{i\lambda 2\pi} = 1.
\end{equation}
This is possible, only if $\lambda$ is an integer number.